# documentDB .net Rest Create Docs with auto gen id

Tags: asp.net, .net, rest, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to create a new document in documentDB via the rest API. I would use the SDK, but im running the project from asp.net core and the SDK isn't compatible yet.

I would like to have documentDB auto generate the id for the document, but I am having problems with my request.

What should I set the ids value to when creating the document via the documentDB rest api (using id based routing)?

Right now I am getting hit with the 400 bad request error.

Ive tried posting it with the following variations on the id:

- No id property
- id: null
- id: ""

The code i am using is basically what was in the github .net rest examples, i have the replace call, get calls working fine.

Here is my code making the request:

```
//Create a document
        verb = "POST";
        resourceType = "docs";
        resourceLink = string.Format("dbs/{0}/colls/{1}/docs", databaseId, collectionId);
        resourceId =string.Format("dbs/{0}/colls/{1}", databaseId, collectionId);


        authHeader = GenerateMasterKeyAuthorizationSignature(verb, resourceId, resourceType, masterKey, "master", "1.0");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("authorization");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authorization", authHeader);

        string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(document);
        StringContent contentMessage = new StringContent(content, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        contentMessage.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        contentMessage.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = null;
        var r = client.PostAsync(baseUri + resourceLink, contentMessage).Result;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

        return r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Can you confirm that it works if you provide an ID? If so, then I suspect that the auto-id functionality is a function of the client-side SDKs. I was able to isolate the GetGuid function in the node.js SDK source and I use that (mostly because I want to keep a handle on it before making an API call. I suspect you could do the same for .NET (find it in the source) and cut-and-paste it into your code. Alternatively, you could download and GUID generation library.

Comment: Yea for now i set it to use an id (concatenating two foreign keys at least 1 is unique) and it works, and hopefully that should be fine for now. I may have to check out the GUID library though or check out that GetGuid function you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should supply a string value for the "id" property. The auto-id functionality (like Larry mentions) is a client-side feature, not part of the REST API. So when consuming directly from REST, you must generate a Guid (or any unique string) and set the "id" property with that value.